# VPN between on prem and GCP: routes shared but ping doesn't go through

Tags: networking, vpn, google-cloud-platform, ipsec, bgp

I have been struggling with the VPN setup between on-prem and GCP for more than a week. I am completely out of ideas at this point, and would love to get some help of network specialists.

### Goal

The end goal is simple: to get a VM instance on GCP to seamlessly talk to a VM on-prem - but with 2 routers in play.
The setup is something like below:

```
       GCP_VM                                                           OP_VM
    10.0.0.25                                                    10.100.0.200
            |                                                    |
            |                                           (DC Router Gateway)
            |                                               10.100.0.80
            |                                                    |
            └-- HA_VPN (AS65001) <==========> Router (AS65002) --┘

     Public IP: xx.xx.xx.xx                   yy.yy.yy.yy
     Advertise: 10.0.0.0/24 BGP               10.100.0.0/24 BGP
  VPN IP Range: 169.254.0.1/30                169.254.0.2 (as Peer)
    Private IP: NA                            10.100.0.50
```

The complication here is that `Router` here is not directly connected to `OP_VM`. This is the on-prem setup we have no control over. `OP_VM` gets its IP `10.100.0.200` from some other router, and our `Router` is put on to the same LAN. We only get a single rack in the data centre, and need to reach `OP_VM` which is hosted by other party (in some other rack). Our rack is associated with `10.100.0.50`.

And with this, I want to be able to get the below work:

```sh
me@GCP_VM:10.0.0.25:~$ ping 10.100.0.200
```

### Current Status

With the above setup, VPN and BGP seem healthy from the logs on both sides.

From `GCP_VM`, I can ping `10.100.0.50` (`Router`) successfully.

```sh
me@GCP_VM:10.0.0.25:~$ ping 10.100.0.50
PING 10.100.0.50 (10.100.0.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.100.0.50: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=24.9 ms
...
```

Also, from `Router`, I could confirm I can ping `10.100.0.200` (`OP_VM`).

```sh
# With the Router setup of something like
#
#     ip route 10.100.0.0/24 gateway 10.100.0.80

root@Router:10.100.0.50:~$ ping 10.100.0.200
ping 10.100.0.200
received from 10.100.0.200: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.583ms
received from 10.100.0.200: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.571ms

2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.571/0.577/0.583 ms
```

From `GCP_VM`, though, ping to `10.100.0.200` (`OP_VM`) goes **missing**.

```sh
# With the Router setup of something like
#
#     ip route 10.100.0.0/24 gateway 10.100.0.80

me@GCP_VM:10.0.0.25:~$ ping 10.100.0.200
PING 10.100.0.200 (10.100.0.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.100.0.200 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3051ms
```

I'm probably misunderstanding the gateway setup, but changing the route like below gives me a different result:

```sh
# With the Router setup of something like
#
#     ip route 10.100.0.0/24 gateway 10.100.0.50
#                                             ~~ <- Router itself

me@GCP_VM:10.0.0.25:~$ ping 10.100.0.200
PING 10.100.0.200 (10.100.0.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.0.2 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.0.2 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.0.2 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.0.2 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.0.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.0.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.0.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.100.0.200 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, +7 errors, 100% packet loss, time 8141ms
pipe 7
```

With this gateway setup, `Router` can no longer ping `OP_VM`. This at least seems to me that VPN is established and IP is advertised correctly. But this does not look right from the actual networking point of view.

### Questions

I don't think there is much more to be done on GCP side, and the issue seems to be purely on the on-prem.

Is there any setup issues, or concerns that may cause misbehaviour of VPN, BGP, ARP, etc.? What would cause such a case where routes seem to be shared, but cannot actually access them?

---

### Other Notes

- I have confirmed the ARP table on `Router` includes `10.100.0.200`
- I can see the routes propagated in GCP
- I have tested with GCP VPC's Firewall setup to allow `169.254.0.0/30` and `10.100.0.0/24`
- I will need access from GKE in the end, but I have confirmed GKE is getting the same exact behaviour as `GCP_VM`
- `Router` is from Yamaha
- Tried TCPdump (`packetdump` in Yamaha routers), but did not see `10.0.0.25` in the log
- TCPdump did show the trace of `10.0.0.25` when I ran `nmap -Pn 10.100.0.200` from `GCP_VM`, but with single line like this:

```
2019/12/21 16:35:40: LAN1 OUT:IP TCP 10.100.0.227:50516 > 10.103.24.1:80
```

### Update (24th Dec)

I have done `tcpdump` for simple ping between `GCP_VM` and `Router`.

**From `GCP_VM` to `Router`** (logs from `GCP_VM`)

```sh
$ ping 10.100.0.50 > /dev/null &
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 | grep 10.100
...
18:49:18.696178 IP GCP_VM.(snip) > 10.100.0.50: ICMP echo request
, id 32396, seq 0, length 64
18:49:18.700395 IP 10.100.0.50 > GCP_VM.(snip): ICMP echo reply, 
id 32396, seq 0, length 64
```

**From `Router` to `GCP_VM`** (logs from `GCP_VM`)

```sh
# ping from Router, with `ping 10.0.0.25`
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 | grep 169.254
...
18:40:18.554555 IP 169.254.0.2 > GCP_VM.(snip): ICMP echo request,
 id 3369, seq 0, length 72
18:40:18.554586 IP GCP_VM.(snip) > 169.254.0.2: ICMP echo reply, i
d 3369, seq 0, length 72
```

Although `tcpdump` shows the reply is being sent here, it is never received by `Router`.
Also, ping to `169.254.0.2` from `GCP_VM` gets no reply.

```sh
$ ping 169.254.0.2 > /dev/null &
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 | grep 169.254
...
18:59:07.113101 IP GCP_VM.(snip) > 169.254.0.2: ICMP echo request, i
d 32531, seq 0, length 64
18:59:08.137103 IP GCP_VM.(snip) > 169.254.0.2: ICMP echo request, i
d 32531, seq 1, length 64
...
```

### Update (27th Dec)

Ping from the `Router` was successful after setting its source address to `10.100.0.50`, as it was trying to use `169.254.0.2` by default.

The ping still doesn't reach `OP_VM`, and I'm still facing NAT configuration issue to ensure the translation goes correctly.

### Update (31st Dec)

The connection has been finally set up. I'll be summarising the steps taken in a separate answer to declutter the question.

Comment: Please add your solution as you mentioned in your last update.

Comment: I have added further clarification and solution I had to put in place in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing and debugging, I have resolved the connection issue between GCP and on-prem. The below is the steps taken, and also considerations made while pinpointing the problem.

### Analyse Traffic from Both Directions

I was lacking the consideration to dissect the traffic from *both directions*. This means breaking down how each packet would travel from/to source/destination, and that would give clear view of where the root cause could lie.

**Packet from GCP to on-prem**

1. Packet sent from `GCP_VM` (`10.0.0.25`) to `HA_VPN` (`169.254.0.1/30`)
2. Packet sent from `GCP_VM` (`10.0.0.25`) to `Router (AS65002)` (`10.100.0.50`)
3. Packet sent from `GCP_VM` (`10.0.0.25`) to `DC Router Gateway` (`10.100.0.80`)
4. Packet sent from `GCP_VM` (`10.0.0.25`) to `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`)
5. Packet sent from `Router (AS65002)` (`10.100.0.50`) to `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`)

**Packets from on-prem to GCP (return route)**

6. Packet sent from `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`) to `Router (AS65002)` (`10.100.0.50`)
7. Packet sent from `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`) to `GCP_VM` (`10.0.0.25`)
8. Packet sent from `Router (AS65002)` (`10.100.0.50`) to `GCP_VM` (`10.0.0.25`)

---

Given the above checkpoints, the followings were the status:

1. This was not tested, as Cloud VPN endpoint (`169.254.0.1/30`) was not part of routes in VPC
2. I could confirm the `ping` hitting `Router (AS65002)` (`10.100.0.50`), and also response returned (this means the corresponding #9 is also confirmed)
3. I could **NOT** confirm the `ping` hitting `DC Router Gateway` (`10.100.0.80`), as ping did not receive response
4. I could **NOT** confirm the `ping` hitting `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`), as ping did not receive response
5. I could confirm the `ping` hitting `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`), and also response returned (this means the corresponding #7 is also confirmed)
6. As mentioned, #6 confirmed this traffic as well
7. **No traffic matches this case**
8. As mentioned, #2 confirmed this traffic as well

The below is the diagram to describe the situation

```
    GCP_VM     HA_VPN (AS65001)     Router (AS65002)   (DC Router Gateway)    OP_VM
 10.0.0.25                          10.100.0.50        10.100.0.80            10.100.0.200

1. NA
2.    +--------------------------------> OK (response returned)
3.    +----------------------------------------------------x NG?
4.    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------x NG?
5.                                      +-----------------------------------------> OK (response returned)
6.                                   OK <-----------------------------------------+
7. No matching traffic
8. OK <--------------------------------+
```

---

This clarifies that any traffic initiating from `GCP_VM` leaves possible 2 issues:

- **Possibility A**. Packet is not reaching `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`)
- **Possibility B**. Packet is reaching `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`), but response is not getting back to `Router (AS65002)` (`10.100.0.50`)

I could confirm with #5 and #6 above that the packet does reach `OP_VM` (`10.100.0.200`) when initiated at `Router (AS65002)` (`10.100.0.50`). That means, **Possibility A** is unlikely. The routing itself is working as it should.

This meant there is a high chance that `ping` response is lost, and never hitting `Router (AS65002)` (`10.100.0.50`) back. And for my specific case here, this **Possibility B** was the root cause of the problem.

I could confirm this is the case by creating a mock network mimicking the same setup as above, and using Wireshark to listen at each point. It meant that the diagram below is the actual case.

```
    GCP_VM     HA_VPN (AS65001)     Router (AS65002)   (DC Router Gateway)    OP_VM
 10.0.0.25                          10.100.0.50        10.100.0.80            10.100.0.200

1. NA
2.    +--------------------------------> OK (response returned)
3.    +----------------------------------------------------> OK
4.    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------> OK
5.                                      +-----------------------------------------> OK (response returned)
6.                                   OK <-----------------------------------------+
7.               Where should I sent packet to??  LOST ---------------------------+
8. OK <--------------------------------+
```

### Solution

In my case, when the traffic initiates at `GCP_VM`, the source IP was set to `10.0.0.25`. This meant, when `OP_VM` tries to send the traffic back, it couldn't find where `10.0.0.25`, and packet was lost.

I had to add a static NAT entry at `Router (AS65002)` to map source IP of `10.0.0.25` to `10.100.0.50` when the packet leaves `Router (AS65002)`, so that the `OP_VM` can properly route the traffic back to `Router (AS65002)`. After the response is received, NAT takes effect again, and `Router (AS65002)` then replaces `10.100.0.50` with `10.0.0.25`, and sends packets back to `GCP_VM`.

Answer (score 2):

It's looks like a routing problem on-prem. I think, `OP_VM` doesn't have a route to `10.0.0.0/24` and as result send it to the default gateway `DC Router Gateway` and there it's dropped because `DC Router Gateway (10.100.0.80)` also doesn't have route to `10.0.0.0/24` (because you have peering at `Router`).

To solve it you should set a static route at `OP_VM` to `10.0.0.0/24` via `Router` and keep `DC Router Gateway` as a default gateway.

You have to remove route `ip route 10.100.0.0/24 gateway 10.100.0.50` from `Router`- network `10.100.0.0/24` is directly connected to him.

**EDIT**

> From GCP_VM, I can ping 10.100.0.50 (Router) successfully.

At this point it looks like you have properly configured peering between `Router` and `HA_VPN`.

You should be able to ping `GCP_VM` and `OP_VM` from `Router` and also `Router` from `OP_VM` to be on a right path.

> With the Router setup of something like
>
> ```
>  ip route 10.100.0.0/24 gateway 10.100.0.80
> ```
>
> With the Router setup of something like
>
> ```
>  ip route 10.100.0.0/24 gateway 10.100.0.80
> ```

You don't need these routes because `Router` is directly connected to subnet `10.100.0.0/24` and has an IP `10.100.0.50`

> From GCP_VM, though, ping to 10.100.0.200 (OP_VM) goes missing.

It's expected because `OP_VM` and `DC Router Gateway` don't have a route to `10.0.0.0/24` as I mentioned above and can't reply and you have to set a static route at `OP_VM` to `10.0.0.0/24` via `Router` and keep `DC Router Gateway` as a default gateway.

**EDIT 2** `OP_VM` sent replies to `DC Router Gateway` because it's doesn't have a route to 10.100.0.0/24 and it try to reach it via default gateway, and at `DC Router Gateway` they've dropped because there's no route also.

You should add a static route at `OP_VM` or at `DC Router Gateway` to `10.100.0.0/24` to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'm suspecting that scenario as well. `10.0.0.0/24` is advertised to the `Router` via BGP, and that should be sufficient for the routing. However, I am seeing the ping from `Router` to `10.0.0.25` failing, although the other way around works. There seems to be something missing in the `Router`, or potentially GCP FW setup.

Comment: Firewall at GCP should accept on-prem network `10.100.0.0/24` you advertise via BGP (must be in the routing table at `Router` and after peering at`HA_VPN`) and vise verse firewall on-prem should accept cloud network `10.0.0.0/24` (network `10.0.0.0/24` must be in the routing table of `HA_VPN` and after peering at `Router`). You shoud be able to ping everything in cloud from `Router` and vise versa. What's the default gateway of yor `Router`?

Comment: FW is set on GCP to allow the traffic to/from `10.100.0.0/24`, and on-prem has the same for `10.0.0.0/24`. I have done the tcpdump on both ends, and it does look like the ICMP going through both routes and passing the FW correctly. I have updated the original question with some more details. But now it looks like the route from GCP to `169.254.0.2` isn't going through. At this point, I'm not sure if this has to do with the main issue of `GCP_VM` not being able to reach `10.100.0.200` though...

Comment: If firewalls are configured properly check the routing tables at  `Router` and `HA_VPN`. Why did you decided to use link-local IP addresses for peering?

Comment: Both routing tables show each other (GCP side with VPC Routes, `Router` with `ip route`). I used the link-local IP addresses by following the [GCP doc for HA VPN setup](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-ha-vpn). At this point, my hypothesis is that `OP_VM` (the one I don't have control over) rejects incoming packet from `10.0.0.25`, and ping from `Router` to `GCP_VM` is a separate problem (probably with GCP routes not understanding the link-local IP). As to the former problem, I probably need to NAT to use `10.100.0.0/24` range. I'm not sure about the latter.

Comment: I think that `OP_VM` sent replies to `DC Router Gateway` because it's doesn't have a route to `10.100.0.0/24` and it try to reach it via default gateway, and at `DC Router Gateway` they've dropped because there's no route also. You should add a static route at `OP_VM` or at `DC Router Gateway` to `10.100.0.0/24` to solve it.

Comment: That may well be the case. Neither `OP_VM` nor `DC Router Gateway` are under my control, so I will need to have a third party vendor to look into them. While I wait for the help from that end, I will see if NAT is going to help.

Comment: Well, NAT at `Router` could solve the problem, but static route, in my opinion, is the best way to do it.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Please mark my post as "accepted" if my solution was helpful.

Comment: I have been working on this day in day out, but still haven't solved the problem yet. There is still a couple of pieces not working around NAT and routing, which is still a mystery. Your support was certainly helpful and I appreciate it, but I will hold off from accepting answer until the problem is fully resolved, as I'm also desperate for a proper solution.